# How can I check if an object with specific property exists in a Ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects *and the object looks something *like this `{seat_id, room_id, date_created};`
I want to find if in that array there is an object which has seat_id equal to a specific value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
arr.any?{|a| a.seat_id == "value"}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because you want to find IF there is the element. But if you want to find WHERE the element is, the other answer is the correct one.

Comment: I want to find IF there is an element. Thanks @davidrac

Answer (score 20):

Here:

```
arr.find_index {|item| item.seat_id == other.seat_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.map{|a| a.seat_id == "value"}
```

It will return array of true and false value, true value are matching value.